# Exporting a spreadsheet to PDF - is it possible to keep the computations active?

Tags: pdf, format, spreadsheet

I've implemented a card game in a spreadsheet (I'm using Apache OpenOffice, but can get my stuff converted to "normal" MS Xcel if need be).

What my sheet does is in fact deal out four cards at a time, from a deck that only contains aces (counted as ones)  and twos through tens - so basically it's four random number generators activated by a keystroke.

The computer parts end here. The players are supposed to do stuff with the four numbers using their heads, paper and pencils.

Now I'd like to convert the spreadsheet to pdf so I can share it with people without them having to use Apache, Xcel or any other spreadsheet software. But when I export the content, the pdf file just shows the numbers last generated; I cannot make it "reshuffle" and deal again. Is it at all possible?

Comment: Well my whole idea of exporting to pdf is to have a format (*portable* document format) that everyone on any platform can view and enjoy. If PS requires a special viewer I am not particularly attracted to it. Also, the example in your link uses Python - now that is a language I wasted a year trying to learn. Which I failed. I guess my programming years may be a few more, but my years of learning new programming paradigms are definitely over.  I do have some experience with js though - if it can somehow be incorporated in a pdf, it might be my solution.

Answer (score 0):

A direct conversion is not possible; Excel macros and JavaScript are too far away from each other.

You will have to recreate the logic using Acrobat JavaScript.